# Pass and set variable to all controllers - Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony

How do I pass a variable to all controllers in my project?

Let's say I have one Entity called User that relates to Company, and Company relates to Products, Customers and others entities.

When the User enters the app, he will choose in a dropdown which Company he will use (because he can have more than 1 company).

Right now I am injecting TokenStorageInterface and doing this in my controllers

```
$user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```

and

```
$form->add('company', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Company::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'label' => 'Company:',
                'choices' => $user->getCompanies()
            ]);
```

but the problem is that I am repeating this code in every form and in every controller, and I have a lot.
Also, I dont want to have a dropdown with the Companies in every form, I would like to save the company_id automatic based on his choice when he entered the app, so all CRUD operations would be saved with this company_id in the FK.
And if the User want to change the Company, he just go to a fixed dropdown in the navbar (for example), and change it, changing the ID in this global variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about Symfony Form Events? https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Just create service and inject it where you need. (your service will contain logic for form creation..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/templating/embedding_controllers.html in your template.

The best way is to create own service that provides necessary logic. Then load this service into the controller and embed this action in template.

Comment: Cool, I followed this example on the link and now I can display a list of Companies embedding the Controller.

Comment: But how exactly can I pass the selected value to the form?
The embed controller is in base template and the form is in another template that extends the base one.

My embed html is the following:
https://pastebin.com/zVPT5LJ9

Comment: you need to set form action with a path to your controller which you embed